# Deployment on Google App Engine - Django, Vagrant, Ansible

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, vagrant, ansible

I want to deploy `Django` project on `google app engine`

Following are the current situations.

1. I have a code on `GITHUB`
2. `Djnago` project has setup using `Vagrant`, `Ansible`, `VirtualBox`

I am completely new for `cloud base deployments`.

Need help to achieve this.

I checked `google docs` but there are couple of options for django related deployment, I am not sure which to pick for `vagrant` and `ansible`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit too generic as it stands - making it here rather than comment for clarity.

If you're talking about deploying to GAE (Google App Engine) then most likely you cannot re-use your Ansible scripts as you've been writing for vagrant. As it may be possible to use Ansible to deploy on GAE, most people I know are using standard google [procedure](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine) to deploy their app.

If you plan to use GCE (Google Compute Engine, a layer down in the infrastructure), you would be able to use your existing Ansible provisioning scripts (maybe with slight modification), follow along the [Ansible documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/guide_gce.html)

Comment: Thank you. Can you suggest some `links` to follow

Comment: I had 2 links in the answer, one of each case https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine and http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/guide_gce.html; should be good enough as a starting point